# Find auto generated id of textbox on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<td id="RB_0_val_1">
<label for="RB_0_value_field_1" style="display:none;">Field   Value</label>   
<input type="text" id="RB_0_value_field_1"></td>
<td id="RB_0_extra_1"><input type="button" value="Select.." id="File"></td>
```

Now i need to find the id of textbox on th click of button.So i am using

```
 var  textboxid=$('input[id="File"]').closest('input[type="text"]').attr("id");
```

but value returned is undefined.
The id of the textbox is auto generated so i need to find the id on the click of the button.
How to do this?

Comment: see my updated answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that the tds are inside a tr.

You can make this selector

```
var  textboxid=$('input#File').parents('tr').find('label + input').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.parentsUntil` , `:has()`

```js
$("#File").click(function() {
var textboxid = $(this).parentsUntil("td:has(:text)").find(":text").attr("id")
console.log(textboxid)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td id="RB_0_val_1">
        <label for="RB_0_value_field_1" style="display:none;">Field Value</label>
        <input type="text" id="RB_0_value_field_1">
      </td>
      <td id="RB_0_extra_1">
        <input type="button" value="Select.." id="File">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please replace your code with my code where just add prev() function.

```
var textboxid=$('input[id="File"]').prev().closest('input[type="text"]').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jquery [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) api, for doing that. Try the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mphgs678/2/)

**Javascript code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#File').click(function(e){
        console.log($(this).prev('input[type=text]').prop('id'));
        alert($(this).prev('input[type=text]').prop('id'));
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

EDIT : For Updated markup provided in [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mphgs678/5/), I have used [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) [.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) and [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) jquery api

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#File').click(function (e) {
               var id = $(this).closest('td').prev('td').find('input[type=text]').prop('id');    
               alert(id);
               e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Hope this helps .....

Comment: Note, `.prev()` does not return same results when `td` is child element of `tr` , `tbody` elements http://jsfiddle.net/mphgs678/4/

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe (haven't tried it) :

```
var textboxid = $('#File').parent().find('input[type=text]').first().attr("id");
```

Should it be triggered by a click or something ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the text box is in different td, try this:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#File').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).parent().prev('td').children('input[type=text]').prop('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="RB_0_val_1">
      <label for="RB_0_value_field_1" style="display:none;">Field Value</label>
      <input type="text" id="RB_0_value_field_1">
    </td>
    <td id="RB_0_extra_1">
      <input type="button" value="Select.." id="File">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/dav5wtwy/6/)

```
 $$(document).on('click', '#File', function() {
var qwe = $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]');
            alert(qwe.attr('id'));
    });
```